# How to check a particular solution to a inhomogeneous PDE?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

My assignment asked to check $\frac{1}{6}$($e^{x+y}-e^{3x-y}$) is a particular solution to

$$2u_x + 5u_y + 29u = (6e^{x+y}-5e^{3x-y})$$

In general, as I study from the book, we can check a solution whether it solves PDE or not by taking partial differentiate respect to $x$ and $y$, plug them in and compare both side see if they are equal.  However, I'm stuck on check a particular solution to the PDE, not sure what I'm missing here, any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your right hand side should be $6\mathrm e^{x + y} - 5\mathrm e^{3x - y}$.

Let $u(x, y) = \frac{1}{6} (\mathrm e^{x + y} - \mathrm e^{3x - y})$. Then $u_x = \frac{1}{6} (\mathrm e^{x + y} - 3 \mathrm e^{3x - y})$ and $u_y = \frac{1}{6}(\mathrm e^{x + y} + \mathrm e^{3x - y})$. Now plug this into the left hand side:

\begin{align} 2 u_x + 5 u_y + 29 u &= \frac{2}{6} (\mathrm e^{x + y} - 3 \mathrm e^{3x - y}) + \frac{5}{6}(\mathrm e^{x + y} + \mathrm e^{3x - y}) + \frac{29}{6} (\mathrm e^{x + y} - \mathrm e^{3x - y}) \\ &= \frac{36}{6}\mathrm e^{x + y} - \frac{30}{6} \mathrm e^{3x - y} \\ &= 6 \mathrm e^{x + y} - 5 \mathrm e^{3x - y},\end{align}

so $u$ is indeed a particular solution.

Comment: Thanks for pointing our, I fixed my question, so this is basically same as checking a solution whether it solves a homogeneous equation. For some reasons, when I took ODE 2 years ago, I barely remember I have to find particular solution separately. PDE seems no need to do that.

Comment: If the solution shall satisfy a homogeneous equation, the right hand side have to be $= 0$. What you probably mean is that if you want to get the general solution of a linear equation, you have to calculate the general homogeneous solution and one particular solution and take their sum.

Comment: Exactly, thank you for your help, really appreciate.